# Data in express session disappear when upload file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, express-session

I'm developing a web server and trying to make upload file route. But I need only people who logged in can upload a file. So I add middleware that checks if the session data's available. But session data alway is undefined in this route.

I tried to reload and to regenerate session but it still is undefined. And I changed the library from "multer" to "express-fileupload" but it does not effect. Maybe because the type of content is multipart-form-data. I'm not sure.

Session middleware set up.

```
const sessionMidleware = session({
  secret: 'My secret key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
})

app.use(sessionMidleware)
```

The middleware that I inserted for debugging.

```
app.post(
  '/sendinvoice',
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    next()
  },
  uploadCustomerInvoice().fields([
    { name: 'file', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'course_id', maxCount: 1 },
  ]),
  customerInvoice,
)
```

this is a function that I use for setting up a session in other routes when login and register.

```
module.exports = (req, profile, courses) => {
  req.session.profile = profile
  req.session.courses = courses
  req.session.isSuper = false
  req.session.isAdmin = false
  req.session.save()
}
```

I expect the output of req.session.profile to object that store user data, but the actual output is undefined.

Comment: where are you SETTING the session?

Comment: top of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that session disappeared because I forgot to send the cookie with the request. I'm using Fetch API. So I add `credentials: 'include'` to the header then it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions get overridden while using multer, this will happen with cls package also.

Try to add a promise when you call multer instance , and on resolve you proceed with the next line execution. I think this should solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what multer instance is. My English isn't good.  Did you mean uploadCustomerInvoice function?

Comment: It will be something like ```
var upload = multer(object); add a promise to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SET` a session key in one route to use it in another. For example a login.

1. You login, a session is set. Which is used to verify user at later time.
2. Every route that needs auth needs to check if the session key exists.
3. If exists, proceeds. Otherwise, it doesn't.

So in your case,

```
app.post('/login', (req,res) =>{
    //here check if logged in
    if(login){
        // Set the session
        req.session.someKey = someDataToVerifyUser;
    }
})

app.post('/upload', (req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.session.someKey && someVerification(req.session.someKey)){
        next();
    }else{
        res.status(400).send('Not Authorized')
    }
}, ..multer..., (req,res)=> {...})
```

**EDIT:**
You can use [`passport-js`](http://www.passportjs.org/) to make the signup and login thing seamless.

**EDIT2:**
I have made a minimal example, see if it helps:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router()
const session = require('express-session');
var multer = require('multer')

var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' })

var sess = {
    secret: 'mySecret',
    cookie: { token: null },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true
};

app.use(session(sess));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hit The GET /:")
    req.session.token = 'hello';
    console.log("Setting the session:"+req.session.token+"\n"); // Outputs 'hello'
    res.send(req.session.token);
});
app.get('/me', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hit The GET /me:")
    console.log(`Printing the Session: ${req.session.token}\n`);
    res.send(req.session.token);
});
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("Hit The POST /me:")
        console.log(`THERE IT IS ${req.session.token}\n`);
        next()
    },
    upload.single('avatar'),
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.dir(req.file);
        res.json(req.file)
    })

app.listen(8888, () => {
    console.log('Server Running At: 8888');
})
```

And this is the Console output:

```
Server Running At: 8888
Hit The GET /:
Setting the session:hello

Hit The GET /me:
Printing the Session: hello

Hit The POST /me:
THERE IT IS hello

{ fieldname: 'avatar',
  originalname: '304.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: './uploads/',
  filename: '340cae7033576062253339d04519ed8a',
  path: 'uploads/340cae7033576062253339d04519ed8a',
  size: 4093 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already have two routes that set req.session.profile. In the post, I just debug by middleware.

Comment: Add the minimalistic version of the routes to the question, that's why I asked where are you setting the session.

Comment: OK, I will add it to my post.

Comment: How are you using the function that you just added?

Comment: I just invoke it like this in login route and it work.
`addUserSession(req, result.profile, result.courses, false) `

Comment: The session is updated. Every other route can access req.session.profile.

Comment: Edited the answer, added a minimal working example and the output.

Comment: I copied your code and add it to my code. It worked fine in '/' and '/me' get route. But it still undefined in post route. Did you run your code?

Comment: Yes I have attached the output also.

Comment: Thank you. I may miss something. I will try it again.